# Whether following types of code can be present in view in mvc(codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to **MVC & codeigniter** and want to know whether its okay to have following types of code in **view files**

```
if(strcasecmp($_SESSION['role'],'author')==0)
{
   some code
}
```

or

```
 if($this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by'))
 {
    some code
 }
```

i.e. **checking existence of a session object or flashdata in a view file**

Also,I would want to know whether creating table rows dynamically in a view file using **foreach** loop construct(like given below) is alright as per **MVC**

```
<?php foreach($items as $item){ ?>

  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $item->name; ?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $item->price; ?> </td>
  </tr> 
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: [CodeIgniter encourages MVC, but does not force it on you.](https://www.codeigniter.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Word Answer is Yes! No Problem

It is fine to access Session Variables in Views . Session are variable to store information.

As Long as you are not putting Business Logic Inside Your View . you can use anything in views . The Case you mentioned you are using is What I will call "Display Logic" that is used to check which / What /From Where/ How content will be shown .

**From Two Code Samples you Show Following One is Correct to Use with MVC**

```
 if($this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by'))
 {
    some code
 }
```

**You For Loop Code is also having no problem with MVC**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But please tell me are you sure about the fact that I can do something like if($this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by'))
 {
    echo $this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by')
 } in a view file.I ask this as I don't want to move forward with my code before I am 100% sure.Also as you can read above some people have written contradictory comments.Many many thanks again

Comment: @stackoverflownewbie as i stated in my answer . it is not recommended to use Business logic in Views . using this is only a session check that you are doing . So its not business logic its just display logic that is only manipulating what to show depends on certain condition So that's not a heavy business logic it can be called as Display Logic 

Let me know if you have any other confussion and accept answer if it helps you

Comment: Please read my comment below; the check is indeed display logic, but you are reading a model from the view right now. That is evil ;)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good practice to check session values within the view. Check it within controller and pass the relevant data to view

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have a question.Am I not allowed to check the  existence of a particular session value in the view before I can echo it or use the check to echo something else.For example how to handle a situation like if a particular session value or flashdata value exist an input box will be show otherwise it will not be shown.Don't we have to write that check code(for displaying the input box) in the view file itself?

Comment: Check if session value is set, inject it into view.

In your view, check if the variable is set - echo it

This will make sure that your code is not dependent on session

Answer (score 1):

It goes completely against the idea of the [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) principe.

In (really) short; the model is responsible for managing data entities, [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, how a data entity should look like, etc. The controller is responsible for any [business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic). Which means; when should I update a record, should this data be available to user x, etc. The view is merely responsible for displaying data that is already available. Nothing more, nothing less.

So in your example; the Controller should check session data, flash data, whatever, and send the processed data to the view. Eg:

```
if( strcasecmp($_SESSION['role'],'author') === 0 )
{
    $can_edit = true;
    $message = 'You can edit! Go ahead';
} else {
    $can_edit = false;
    $message = 'You do not have sufficient rights to edit this entity';
}
```

Now pass these variables to the view, there you can do something like:

```
<?php if ( $can_edit ): ?>
    <form action="POST">
        <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
        <textarea name="content"><?php echo $entity->content; ?></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $message; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But may be I am not being clear with my examples.The code for flashdata if($this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by'))
 {
    echo $this->session->flashdata('edition_done_by');
 }  .                                                                                                        All I am doing in my view file is checking whether flashdata is set so that I can echo it.But the setting of flashdata and values for session objects are set in model.Am I not allowed to check the existence of flashdata or session objects before echoing them  in the  view in the view itself

Comment: Your guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Nope, that's because of the basic principle of separation of concerns. Imagine that you are changing your app, and you are not storing this info in the session/flashdata anymore, but in a database, in a cookie, or whatever. Now you have to update your view everywhere. But if you checked the data in the controller, directly from the model, you would only have to edit the model. Furthermore; you don't want to have business logic in your view because your view will be cluttered, and designing views is another job then writing business logic.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment.I agree with you that business logic should not be written in views.But whether simply echoing, say an error message ,which has been set as an flashdata(and valid only for current request) will be considered as business logic, because the error message was set(as a flashdata) using the controller and model based on a validation logic written in the controller.I just wrote the code for checking whether the error message exist as flashdata in my view nothing more.If you read a comment below,another user has said that such a code is called display logic.

Comment: Well, just doing `if ( $editing_done_by ) { echo $editing_done_by; }` is perfectly fine, that _is_ indeed display logic. But it's calling the `$this->session` object directly what is problematic, because basically the `session` object is a `Model`, and you should not call models directly from the view. It seems at first you are doing extra work by first setting the variable in the controller, but as your app grows, you'll be grateful that you have set it up correctly. Because yet again; imagine what would happen if you don't want to store that data in your session anymore, but somewhere else..